# Large PDF display Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

What is considered a large PDF when it comes to Blazor server?

I am trying to load a 26mb 400 page PDF document that's probably not optimized into a Syncfusion PDF viewer in my Blazor Server app. Have got some mixed feedback that large files are not server-side friendly because of the SignalR dependency.

What is the best option, to split the PDF into chunks and have the users view them in increments of 50 pages?

Microsoft docs seem to say that large files are 250mb+, but does that mean downloading via JS Interop or actually displaying in your web page. I have a feeling there is a difference.

I need to use Syncfusion PDF Viewer (or any other PDF viewing component), because the highlighting/annotating is crucial to my business.

I have been playing with WASM for the whole day seeing if it will justify migrating the project but last resort am asking here.

Syncfusion wants me to use MemoryStream which I don't know if I'm comfortable with, nor can I serialize the whole thing in Base64 because I get some Buffer is too big error.

Comment: They can annotate outside the browser, but we want them to have the ability to annotate within the application as well

Comment: You can also use the help of virtualization to load the PDF faster.

Comment: Can you expand on using virtualization on the Syncfusion PDF viewer

Comment: you can make pdf=>html conversion and separate images from markup and this will give you an user friendly web bpage with pdf content